# Making Jquery work within a page that was received via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to write some jquery stuff within a page(content) that is originally being received via ajax. But its not working. If I make the page non received via ajax, it works perfect. However I wanted the current page(requested via ajax) to work with the jquery search i'm doing. I've put this code on the page requesting the ajax content, not working, and then I tried putting it on the ajax requested content.

The Page that has the ajax content has this:

and its suppose to use the below javascript function

Thank You

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    var data = {items: [
            {value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
            {value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
            {value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
            {value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
            {value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
            {value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
        ]};
    $("div.search input").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to understand what's going on in your page without seeing more of your code. Would your problem be that you're expecting $(document).ready to be run only after your ajax content is loaded? If that's the case, then you should know that it's run after the page is fully loaded, and ajax requests aren't included in this - they're separate.

If this actually is your problem, you can fix it by moving everything inside of $(document).ready to the ajax callback function.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting it into a custom function then calling that function after the content has been loaded?

```
function stuff() {

    var data = {items: [
            {value: "21", name: "Mick Jagger"},
            {value: "43", name: "Johnny Storm"},
            {value: "46", name: "Richard Hatch"},
            {value: "54", name: "Kelly Slater"},
            {value: "55", name: "Rudy Hamilton"},
            {value: "79", name: "Michael Jordan"}
        ]};

    $("div.search input").autoSuggest(data.items, {selectedItemProp: "name", searchObjProps: "name"});

}

$(function() {
    $('#content').load('something.html', function() {
        stuff();
    });
});
```